# Calculation average in sql field wise

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sample table:

```
Title                                            Author             Rating Publisher             Binding           Dateread   Price
Airframe                                         Michael Crichton        5 Arrow Books           Paperback         2001-11-10     0
Prey                                             Michael Crichton        5 Avon                  Paperback         2001-05-11     0
Congo                                            Michael Crichton        5 Avon                  Paperback         2001-04-10     0
The Lost World (Jurassic Park, #2)               Michael Crichton        5 Alfred A. Knopf, Inc. Mass Market P...  2001-12-10     0
Sphere                                           Michael Crichton        5 Ballantine Books      Paperback         2001-03-11     0
Timeline                                         Michael Crichton        4 Arrow Books           Mass Market P...  2001-02-10     0
Jaya: An Illustrated Retelling of the Mahabarata Devdutt Pattanaik       5 Penguin Global        Paperback         2001-02-11     0
The Pregnant King                                Devdutt Pattanaik       5 Penguin Books India   Paperback         2001-03-11     0
State of Fear                                    Michael Crichton        5 Avon Books            Paperback         2015-06-11     0
The Godfather                                    Mario Puzo              5 NAL                   Paperback         2001-12-08     0
```

I want to calculate :

1. Average rating of each author ( Highest first and excluding those authors which have only 1 book and if two authors have same ratings, the author with more books comes first.)
2. Average rating of book year wise. ( Highest First )

Can anyone help?

Comment: `select author, avg(rating) from ... group by author`. The rest is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
Select Avg(Rating), Author
From BooksDB
Group by Author
Order by Avg(Rating) DESC

Select Avg(Rating), Title
From BooksDB
Group by Title
Order by Avg(Rating) DESC
```